# Automatically close extension dialog in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape extension dialog boxes defined with inx have predefined "Apply" and "Close" buttons.

After clicking "Apply" and doing whatever work the dialog box controls the dialog box remains there. To get rid of it the user most click on "Close".

How can I make the dialog box automatically close after the "Apply" work has been done?